# Windows Authentication working on localhost but not on other site on IIS

Tags: windows, iis, windows-authentication

I'm trying to set up a simple html/css/js only site on my local IIS that uses Windows Authentication.

So far I just a have a c://mysite/index.html file

When I point the default IIS website (i.e http://localhost) to this folder and enable Windows Authentication, I am shown the login dialog when I browse to it. When I enter my creds it then shows the index.html fine. But when I setup a new IIS site (e.g http://local.mysite I have a host entry for this) pointing to the same folder, with Windows Authentication enabled, I cannot get passed the login dialog. It just redisplays as if the login creds were wrong, but I'm entering the same creds as I did in http://localhost.

I have added http://local.mysite to the local intranet zone in Internet Options, but this doesn't resolve the issue.

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have KB 3002657 installed. This patch broke windows authentication, and the symptoms are what you mentioned (redisplays login credentials)

[Has March 2015 Patch Tuesday broken 2003 shares?](https://serverfault.com/questions/674541/has-march-2015-patch-tuesday-broken-2003-shares)

http://www.infoworld.com/article/2895900/security/microsoft-netlogon-patch-kb-3002657-woes-continue-kb-3032359-cisco-anyconnect-fix-confirmed.html

Comment: Checked.  I don't have that installed